# How to modify Hibernate's auto-generated running serial number?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss

I am using **Hibernate** (JPA) with **Derby database** - my app server is **Jboss 6.0**.
I have to pre-populate a table with 50000 employee info and for that I have used a standalone  JDBC program. 
Now from my application I also need to insert new employee info on fly, in the same table and at that time I use **JPA** (since it runs within app container).

My Employee class is an Entity bean and has "**Id**" column being primary key with "**@GeneratedValue(strategy = auto)**" annotation so that Hibernate figures out the appropriate running serial no for the primary key (i.e. Id column).

Now the problem is Hibernate always starts this running serial from "1" even if the Employee table already has entries. Thus from application when I try to insert a new record using ***Entitymanager::persist()***, I always get **constrain violation** error like "*duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index*".
This is because hibernate tries to insert the new entry with **Id =1** where as I already have an entry in that table with Id = 1.

My question is

a) how can I update Hibernate'e cache so that my running serial number for "Id" column can be accordingly adjusted? 
I understand it will vary from DB to DB - but is it possible **at all**?

b) Is there  any other way to achieve the same?

c) If I write a standalone JPA program to do the bulk insert (i.e. pre population) and then start my Jboss application, will hibernate be able to determine the right "running serial" no?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion,
- kuntal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) how can I update Hibernate'e cache
> so that my running serial number for
> "Id" column can be accordingly
> adjusted? I understand it will vary
> from DB to DB - but is it possible at
> all?
>
> b) Is there any other way to achieve
> the same?

- @TableGenerator

You can generate primary-key using @TableGenerator which generates the next id according to the value in a table maintained having two fields tableName & its respective id & it updates it accordingly after insertion.

It is responsible for maintaining the correct sequence, you can modify initial value etc.

```
@TableGenerator(name = "TABLE_GEN", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "PERSON_ID", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_GEN")
private int id;
```

> c) If I write a standalone JPA program
> to do the bulk insert (i.e. pre
> population) and then start my Jboss
> application, will hibernate be able to
> determine the right "running serial"
> no?

So at the end, create two generators for - 1) application & 2) standalone program, consuming common table for id generation, so there will be no *duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index*.

Comment: I did not use the "initialValue" since I have to populate the Employee table and thus the initialValue should be the count of employee entries there. So after I populate the Employee table, I updated the SEQUENCE_TABLE with appropriate count (say 100). Then I started my jboss-app, now when I  insert new record, the id startes with 101 and this is what I was expecting. Thanks for the correct solution. Cheers !

Comment: BTW, similar example is here http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing

Answer (score 0):

For configuring cache the hibernate.cfg.xml file is used.The name in property tag must be hibernate.cache.provider_class for activating second-level cache. We can use hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache property, which allows you to activate and deactivate the second-level cache. By default, the second-level cache is activated and uses the EHCache.

Software testing services